# Include polyfills in webpack > 5 in CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, libsodium

I'm trying to use an NPM package called "libsodium-wrappers" inside a browser with React using Create React App, but getting the following error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

After searching the web about this, I found that I may downgrade the "react-scripts" to version 4, but I really don't want to do this, as I will need to reinstall everything and this may break things.

Are there any working solutions to this besides the above one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to a component library you may be using.  I came across you question while attempting to address this very same issue.  I'm using [react-bootstrap-table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) in a project that is causing this issue for me.  I believe I may have resolved it by installing the events package (specifically for react-bootstrap-table2's needs.  In this case maybe try this:

```sh
yarn add path -D
```

Hopefully in this case that may "bump" the needle in a positive direction for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do `yarn add util` (alternatively, `npm install util`). It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).